# for/in loop with string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am relatively new in JavaScript and I found a strange for loop, like this one:

```
for (c in "test message") {
}
```

Usually, something like this is in a foreach loop, and 'c' element should loop the chars (t, e, s, t etc..)... this one loops the integers...?!

Is there some documentation to understand that behavior?

the complete sample follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p>Click the button to loop through the 
        properties of an object named "person".</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x;
            var txt = "";
            var person = { fname: "John", lname: "Doe", age: 25 };
            var myString = "this is a test";

            for (x in myString) {
                txt = txt + x + ':' + myString[x] + '<br/>';
            }

            for (x in person) {
                txt = txt + x + ':' + person[x] + '<br/>';
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the output:

```
0:t
1:h
2:i
3:s
4: 
5:i
6:s
7: 
8:a
9: 
10:t
11:e
12:s
13:t
fname:John
lname:Doe
age:25
```

Comment: This loop just goes trough every element of a given array (in your case an array of characters - a string) and does the work for every element. It does exactly the same thing as for loop, except you do not need to specify the start, end and step of the loop

Comment: @NDraskovic the question is how "key" became an integer... how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript `for..in` works this way:

```
for (var key in objectOrArray) {
    console.log(key, objectOrArray[key]);
}
```

Hence it always outputs the key, which is the character index (0 based) when looping through a string.

You can also use the same behaviour on strings like so:

```
console.log(str[5]); //the 6th character in the string "str"
```

Comment: so, in any array (including string, integer, or object arrays) "key" <il be always an integer?

Comment: @Serge The basic rule of thumb is that it'll return the keys of whatever object you throw into it. If you can use `variable["key"]` then it'll output "key", if you can use `variable[0]` then it will output "0". If you can't use either, then it'll fail.

Answer (score 0):

for..in works for json object, 'x' represents element in the object.
to split string value you can use normal for..loop

```
for (var x = 0; x < myString.length;x++) 
{
txt = txt + x.toString() + ':' + myString[x] + '<br/>';
}
```